# Align Image View to top of the screen in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to align an image [image with space at top of picture](http://www.lachairmassage.com/images/fixspace.jpg)at the top of a Linear Layout in android studio.I have a space as you can see on the picture. I would like to get rid of that space. Tried few things without success!!! Anyone has a clue how to do it??? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.bourgeois.michel.relativesinglescreenapp.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/toppicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/danielarias" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff6600"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Phone"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:text="424-278-8938"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ff6600"/>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/text"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Address: 5867 W 3rd St, Los Angeles, CA 90036"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Learn How To Dance Milonguero Tango Style!"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thursday"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Every Thursday Night"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hour"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text=" 8:30pm to 9:30pm"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Join Us" />
```

Comment: please check screenshot is not added properly

Comment: Please give more information about your problem. Also we can not see any image

Comment: There is not any problem with xml layout please check your image if it has White space inside it

Comment: Put this in your ImageView XML, android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. i tried android:scaleType="centerCrop" and also android:scaleType="fitXY"  and they both work.  For android:adjustViewBounds="true" it did not work. Thank you so much! Did also fix the image so people can see it for future reference .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your ImageView like :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"  
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem can be about your image sources width and height. There is no marginTop in your xml. Give a try like adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

in `ImageView` parameters,adding `scaleType="fitXY"` will stretch the image so avoid it.

Comment: parameters,adding scaleType="fitXY"  does work Thanks! Strange because i tried yesterday night and my browser was frozen anyway it work thanks Amar!